# Output all CRLs in concat'd CRL file

Tags: openssl

Using openssl, how can you view *all* CRLs from a concat'd file? For instance:

```
$ cat crl1.pem > total_crl.pem
$ cat crl2.pem >> total_crl.pem
$ cat crl3.pem >> total_crl.pem
```

If I want to view all of the CRLs in `total_crl.pem`, I was trying to do:

```
$ openssl crl -in total_crl.pem -noout -text
```

But that only outputs `crl1.pem` from `total_crl.pem`. How can I output *all* of the CRLs from the concat'd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The openssl [crl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/crl.html) command line does not support what you want to do.

You could keep them as separate files and loop through them calling the openssl command line for each file or you can create your own utility using the openssl crl command [code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/crl.c) as a "template" of how to use openssl to manually pull out each crl entry in the file yourself.

Comment: A handy altermative is to use `awk` to create a series of anonymous temporary files, one per PEM block: `awk <bundle -vc="openssl crl -noout -text" '{print|c}/^-----END/{close(c)}'`